GNOME apps crash with SIGSEGV error after switching to Wayland on Ubuntu 24.04 (Nvidia driver)
I switched my Ubuntu 24.04 system to Ubuntu on Wayland (from the bottom-right login settings) to use Waydroid. While Waydroid now works properly, all my other GNOME applications, including Nautilus, the GNOME text editor, and the GNOME control center, crash with the error crashed with SIGSEGV in _dl_close() upon launch.
This issue is confusing because my only changes made were installing a new Ubuntu version, Nvidia drivers, and Waydroid. The error log points to something related to libnvidia-
I've tried switching between Nvidia driver versions in the Additional Drivers panel, but it hasn’t resolved the issue.
Here is the error log:



Problem solved.
It turns out that the Nvidia 535 driver—recommended by Ubuntu and installed by default—is not well supported in Wayland.
Upgrading to at least version 545 is necessary for proper Wayland functionality.
Fortunately, I saw a Nvidia's 545 release notes mentioned improved Wayland support.
So I rebooted my machine, entered recovery mode (press the shift key while booting and selecting advanced mode), accessed the root console, and used 'apt purge nvidia-*' to remove old drivers.
Then, I installed the new driver with 'apt install nvidia-driver-550'.
And it works!
Just sharing in case any newbies encounter a similar issue.
